# NestJs can't find module platform-express even though it's installed in node_modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I was following a tutorial on Udemy in order to setup a NestJS app from scratch. Upon execution using `npx ts-node-dev src/main.ts` I get the error `[PackageLoader] No driver (HTTP) has been selected. In order to take advantage of the default driver, please, ensure to install the "@nestjs/platform-express" package ($ npm install @nestjs/platform-express).`
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling `@nestjs/platform-express` but I still get same error.

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved this issue, I had to delete the entire node_modules folder and then run `npm install` with the same `pckage.json` file.